# Crear array con lista solo con nombres provenientes de otro array

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs

Intento obtener un array únicamente con la lista de nombres de jugadores. Yo creo una constante y guardo hay los nombres iterando con el metodo map todo el array que obtengo de una api utilizando fetch. Pero al ver el resultado con console.log se ve un array con nombres y despues una lista con indice de cada jugador lo cual es como erroneo. la primera imagen es el array completo que obtengo del fetch y despues con el map se ve el resultado en la segunda imagen.

```
export async function searchTeamSquad(id = 11){
try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://transfermarkt-db.p.rapidapi.com/v1/clubs/squad?season_id=2023&locale=DE&club_id=${id}`, {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'transfermarkt-db.p.rapidapi.com'
            }
        });
        if(!response.ok){
            return _handleError(response.status);
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        const players = data.data.map((player) => player.name)
        console.log(players)
        return players;
} catch (err) {
    _throwSpecificError(err);
}
```

}

[image: primera imagen]

[image: segunda imagen]

Comment: No hay problema. La consola primero muestra un resumen el array (hasta X elementos). Luego al presionar la flecha para expandir muestra la lista hacia abajo

Answer (score 1):

En realidad no hay ningún error, los números que vez son los índices del array y el valor en ese índice (`indice: valor`), pero en código es como si vieras un array con nombres normal

```js
["Nombre 1", "Nombre 2", "Nombre 3"]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu aclaracion, y al acompañar  cada nombre con su id, se podria con map?

Comment: Sabes que el sitio dispone de `snippets` donde puedes **ejecutar** el código en vez de colgar una imagen? Te sugiero que edites la respuesta y hagas uso de las herramientas del sitio. Para colgar imagenes ya ecisten las redes antisociales. Te invito a leer [answer].

Comment: @MauricioContreras disculpa, pero es la primera vez que respondo en Stack Overflow

Comment: Ya logre obtener el id y el nombre                                                          
            `const data = await response.json();
            const players = data.data.map(function(player){
                return {id:player.id, name:player.name}
            })
            console.log(players)
            return players;`

Comment: @MiguelRiveraSarmiento puedes desestructurar el `response.json()` de la siguiente manera: `const { data } = await response.json()`. De esta forma evitas hacer el `data.data` y quedaría como `data.map(....)`.

Otra sugerencia es reemplazar la función anónima por una función flecha: `data.map((player) => ({ id: player.id, name: player.name }) );` pero cualquiera de las 2 formas son correctas

Comment: Genial, gracias por tu ayuda.